# Is $\frac{\pi}{e}$ an algebraic integer?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, integers

From what I know, it is still an open question whether or not $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is irrational, but is there a proof that $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is not an algebraic integer?

Comment: Do you mean _algebraic_ integer?

Comment: @Sebastian yes, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: We have: $$\frac{\pi}{e}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\,dx.$$ For what it is worth, I think that starting from there and using orthogonal polynomials it is possible to mimic the proof of the trascendence of $\pi$.

Comment: It is also true that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{(1+x^2)^n}\,dx $$ is a rational multiple of $\frac{\pi}{e}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$.